# Is there a connection between 666 and Solomon?

Tags: exegesis, old-testament, prophecy

There is another question [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/what-is-the-significance-of-the-number-666) that asks for the significance of the number 666.

Most of the answers relate it to papacy, Nero or some other apocalyptic event.

I have read several prophetic websites and they do the same thing. Sum up the numeric value of the alphabets in somebody's name. Multiply it by 2, divide by 3 and it comes to 666.

However I was reading my Bible was surprised to find the following verse -

> 1 Kings 10:14 The weight of the gold that Solomon received yearly was
> 666 talents,
>
> 2 Chronicles 9:13 The weight of the gold that Solomon
> received yearly was 666 talents,

My question is how did everyone over look this? Could it be that the number has nothing to do with papacy or Nero.

There seems to be some sort of connection with Solomon. If so what is it?

Comment: A coincidence?....

Comment: @AffableGeek Doesn't seem likely. 1. The Bible is interconnected in many other places. Such as gospels quoting the Old testament etc. 2. Random coincidences do not occur like that. In a country if two people die at the same time by the same kind of weapon it probably is coincidence. If that happens in same neighborhood you'd expect some sort of connection. Talking in terms of probability, the size of domain/sample space matters.

Comment: The verse in Revelation specifically says the mark is the *name of the beast or the number of its name*.  Seems like quite a stretch to spread it to something like this.

Comment: If you get into numerology, 666 is often in the bible as is 7.  However it is difficult to take the esoteric meaning of something and apply it to the exoteric story.  With that said, Nero could have been the target of some of those stories.  Don't forget that the Jews (and Christians) were not well received by their Roman conquerors.

Comment: @DanAndrews Numerology?? Seriously bro?

Comment: @kurosch It could've just been written that Solomon received a lot of money. But it doesn't say lot of money. Bible specifically quotes a number and repeats it twice. Secondly, did anyone read my comment above? A random coincidence defies the mathematics. Choose a 3 digit number in your head. What is the probability that it's the same I've chosen in my head? 0.1%

Comment: @MonikaMichael I did say "if".  However, I personally do not.  I do enjoy understanding what/how other people think and believe.  "Sum up the numeric value of the alphabets in somebody's name. Multiply it by 2, divide by 3 and it comes to 666." is Numerology.

Comment: @MonikaMichael don't forget that Solomon built temples to other Gods - for his wives.  That got him into a lot of trouble.

Comment: @MonikaMichael - That's like saying King Saul and Paul are connected because they're both named "Saul" and both mentioned in the Bible.

Comment: This question is based (from what I can tell) entirely off of a coincidence, with too much being read into a number popping up. It seems a near impossibility of any answer but mindless speculation, since there is nothing else in scripture linking Solomon to Satanic symbols (that I can find in 30 minutes; if you can find something, then I retract this assertion). I request that this question be closed.

Comment: What an excellent question! It really made me think I will post one possible answer shorty.

Comment: @MonikaMichael It's not quite as unlikely a coincidence as you make it sound. Sure, the probability that my random 3-digit number will be the same as yours is only 0.1%. But if a thousand people each pick a 3-digit number, the probability that at least one of them will pick the same number as you is ... quick calculation ... about 73%. There are lots of numbers in the Bible. I'm sure if this number hadn't matched but you'd noticed that, say, Ahaseurus reigned over 666 provinces (Esther 1) you would have made a similar post.

Comment: @DanAndrews If by "666 is often in the bible as is 7" you mean that 666 occurs frequently in the Bible, I don't think that's true. Besides the example cited here and Revelation, the only occurrance I can find is Ezra 2:13, where it is given as the number of people in one of the families returning from captivity to Israel.

Comment: @Jay you're right, explicitly it's in there that way.  However if you take peoples names and convert them to number, then you'll find 666 more often.  I really don't get into that stuff, so I'm not really the best person to ask about it.  However, I know it exists as a practice for some.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's too much of a stretch.

If we look back at the law for kings in Deuteronomy 17, It prohibits the king from multiplying horses and chariots, wives, and wealth. This is exactly what Solomon is doing in 1 Kings 10-11. Chapter ten begins by commending his great wisdom, but then steps through his decline - that is, he begins violating the rules for kings by multiplying gold (666 talents a year), multiplying horses and chariots, and finally multiplying wives who turn his heart away from following Yahweh. He sets up centers of false worship for all the foreign gods of his wives. So, the number 666 is associated with Solomon in his fall, his abuse of power, and his turning away from true worship of Yahweh.

In Revelation, Jesus sets up worship interactions under the symbol of business transactions - buying and selling.

> I counsel you to buy from me gold refined by fire, so that you may be rich, and white garments so that you may clothe yourself and the shame of your nakedness may not be seen, and salve to anoint your eyes, so that you may see.

This is picked up in chapter 13 with reference to worship in the false temple - the image set up by the beast which must be worshiped on pain of death. Everyone must worship the image, but no one may do so without the mark. The buying and selling referred to here is of the same kind established by Jesus in chapter 3. It is worship - spiritual transactions.

This kind of forced worship of an image set up also has ties back to Nebuchadnezzar.

> King Nebuchadnezzar made an image of gold, whose height was sixty cubits and its breadth six cubits... And the herald proclaimed aloud, “You are commanded, O peoples, nations, and languages, that when you hear the sound of the horn, pipe, lyre, trigon, harp, bagpipe, and every kind of music, you are to fall down and worship the golden image that King Nebuchadnezzar has set up. And whoever does not fall down and worship shall immediately be cast into a burning fiery furnace.”

Nebuchadnezzar is acting as a beast (and later, even more so) and sets up an image to be worshiped. Again, we have six and sixty associated with worship of a false image on pain of death.

All of this comes together in the name and number of the man - 666. This sums up man in his fallen state. The number carries with it the fallen glory of Solomon, his degraded wisdom, his failure to follow the word of God, his abuse of power, and his allowing himself to be turned aside to the worship of impotent gods.

Don't be afraid of symbolism; it's good for you :)

Comment: This is a very interesting answer. I never thought of the buying/selling symbolism here regarding Christian worship. I would add that throughout prophetic literature, beasts depict kingdoms. If this pattern is carried into Revelation 13, the first beast seems to directly refer to Rome's violence against the saints, but could also refer to any kingdom which overtly persecutes the saints. So what of the second beast/kingdom? It is a deceiver. It has horns like a sheep, but exercises all the power of the first beast. It pretends to be a kingdom under God, but actually worships mammon and power.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect coincidence.

You comment that, "The Bible is interconnected in many other places. Such as gospels quoting the Old testament". True, but there's a big difference. Most of these quotes are explicitly identified as quotes. Like Matthew 4:4, "But He answered and said, It is written, ..." There's no question of it being a coincidence. But nowhere does the Bible say, "As the number of the Beast is 666, so Solomon collected 666 talents of gold." Nor is there any clear connection. One is counting letter values in a name; the other is counting pieces of gold. One is identified as evil; the other is simply stated as a matter of fact with no moral judgement. Etc. The only apparent connection is the number.

"Random coincidences do not occur like that. In a country if two people die at the same time by the same kind of weapon it probably is coincidence. If that happens in same neighborhood you'd expect some sort of connection." Exactly. As you add matching facts and conditions, the probability that it is a random coincidence goes down. But the only connection that I can see here is the number. I'm not sure how many numbers there are in the Bible. I just did a text search in an on-line Bible on the word "hundred" and got 559 hits. So assuming that means there are 559 numbers in at least the right general range, and that the probability that one of them would be 666 by pure chance is 1/1000, then the probability that at least one of those numbers would be 666 turns out to be ... punch calculator ... 43%. That's not particularly unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Pardon me for this but I would just like to say that the key to all of this is in the fact that most people begin to look for "THE" antichrist when they see the number 666. That is always a trap as John tells us that there are many antichrists and even then they were among the believers almost 2000 years ago. Though there may be one antichrist to come in the final days of the Babylonian system, aka the new world order, to spend one's time looking for that single being will likely blind one to the real truth of the matter. The antichrist will most likely manifest not just as one being but as the entire Babylonian system as it comes to a head and is then ushered out of this world by the arrival of the spirit of the true king of this world, Jesus, aka, Yahshua.

The number 666 refers to Solomon in the sense that he has surrendered to the lusts of this world. He is thus marked by his predilections and can be identified by his association with them. Those who built Solomon's temple were skilled workers, imported from other kingdoms to do the job. These workers were then and remain today, part of a highly skilled group known as Masons or Freemasons and have always been called upon to build the churches and temples of the world. There can be no one who would deny the connection of the Masons with the illuminati as Freemasonry is in fact, what can be called the "religion" of the "illuminated" ones. It is a long story but to make it short, fallen man as represented first by the rulers of this world in Solomon and equally by the illuminati who boldly lust for power and the glories of Earth, are both marked by the gold and wealth that they seek. Solomon was distracted by temptation and abandoned his God while the illuminati carry it a step further and reject that same God as they turn to worship Lucifer, who has fallen completely and is counted among the lost. They, however, see Lucifer as the one, true god.

The construction of Solomon's Temple is now considered to be a ritual centerpiece of Freemasonry so it is obvious that Solomon and Masonry are closely aligned, if not altogether one in spirit and content. Gold is symbolic of the attractions of this world and Solomon's weakness for it came to identify him with the 666 talents he received every year. Solomon, who lost his spiritual way while continuing to rule his kingdom is precisely representative of and spiritually tied to the equally lost and earthbound illuminati/Freemasonic culture. The antichrist then, can be seen as the love of money, the love of power, and the things of the created world above and beyond the love of the One who created them. Yes, there are many antichrists and there will be one at some point who answers the call of these many antichrists to lead them to their ultimate fate.

Look around you and you will find the symbol of the illuminati everywhere. The triangle or pyramid with the all seeing eye in the center is their major symbol. You will find that pyramid in many places across the world including in many churches which should demonstrate who has constructed them physically and spiritually and who is benefiting from their presence. You will find that same symbol on the back of the US one dollar bill. Are you beginning to get the picture? The Muslims also believe that an antichrist will come and they call it the "Dajjal". They say that the Dajjal will have one eye.

I believe that by now, it should be obvious who and what the antichrist is. Yes, that antichrist will wage war with the saints and will overcome them for a while. it is happening right now in the United States of America. Yes, mighty Babylon is heading for a fall. I wonder how many have realized exactly what that statement means. It may be time to open our eyes.

Love the Truth.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next is just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites), and
[What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I have added a post to your other question [Why is the number 666 considered evil?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/what-is-the-significance-of-the-number-666/9382#9382), so I can apply it to this question. My post is identical with Narnian’s only largely expanded.

Our understanding of what 666 might mean with respect to the weight of Gold that Solomon received annually depends on how we think we are allowed to interpret the Old Testament, in light on the New Testament.  For myself** I prefer to avoid reading too much into the symbolism in the Old Testament, unless it is completely supportive of the plain meaning, verified by the New Testament, and admits are certain amount of uncertainty.** The reason why I feel admitted uncertainty about potential symbolism in the Old Testament is good practice is because we are trying to identify the edge of a shadow, which by nature is obscure. Only in Christ do we see the certain meaning of anything that might be argued as an Old Testament type.

Having put forth my view, I think **I can provide an uncertain possible connection between 666 and this reference without irreverently mangling the plain, literal and intended primary sense.** The literal sense from the context seems to simply show how magnificent and wealthy Solomon had become. However it also seems to be a transition point at which his own wealth became a snare to him and he verges into extravagance, lust and assumes ‘many wives’ in the next chapter. Something God was not pleased with. Therefore regarding spiritual types, we have a conflict of types.  On one hand Solomon’s wealth represents Messiah as risen Lord, while David might represent Messiah on earth. On the other hand, Solomon’s failure and sinfulness might ‘possibly’ slightly be hinted at by 666.

If we assume this uncertain connection, but a connection nevertheless we might imagine that the entire weakness of the image of Solomon and indeed all the types of the Old Testament is being witnessed. Not only do the huge failures of David and Solomon indicate that Messiah must be something far exceeding from those types, but the entire covenant of law is ‘fallen-short, fallen-short, fallen-short’ in terms of its ability to save and bring wealth. Rather a law of grace can only remove the human nature, and the blood of animals can’t cleanse sin. The same imagery is indicated by the Tablets of the law being broken Moses as soon as they were first made, they were never meant to provide what they shadowed but were established as a renewed covenant of works destined to fail due to the weakness of 666. **The Law was added so that sin, or the sinful nature (666) would ‘increase’ according to Romans 5:20. The annual inflow of 666 could indicate this increase of the sinful nature under the shadows of the Law leading to Solomon’s ultimate failure. Clearly as all types of Messiah in the Old Testament he was nothing more than a mere imperfect shadow of a future Christ, proven by the wealth, mirroring Christ's glory, only caused extravagence and a leading to idolatry (like the Roman beast / emporer worship system) to occur.**

> He had seven hundred wives of royal birth and three hundred concubines, and his wives led him astray. As Solomon grew old, his wives turned his heart after other gods, and his heart was not fully devoted to the Lord his God, as the heart of David his father had been. (NIV 1 Kings 11:3-4)

In this symbol of Solomon's wealth still prefigures Christ, but the weakness of those symbols as not having any saving power in themselves, but fully falling short, is seamlessly maintained.

Some might think I am stretching the meaning too far, but that is a fair comment that I would accept, while at the same time believing I may have found a little hidden nugget of scripture because you brought it to my attention. Thank you very much, I like it.

Answer (score -2):

I think everyone stating that it's a coincidence is a fool. 666 doesn't show up a ton of times in the Bible. It only shows up 4 times and I whole-heartedly believe they're connected. In addition to that look at Solomon's role in today's society. In Islam it's believed he built the Temple in cahoots with the jinn (the fallen angels) but Islamic belief thinks the fallen angels aren't demonic (like jewish and christian faith assumes) but instead they believe they are free willed like humans, to do either good or bad. So Solomon works with the fallen angels to build a temple. In addition to that, Solomon is the central figure to freemasonry. The whole system is based on his relationship with King Hiram (a faithless king). Furthermore, Israel is trying so hard to rebuild what???? - The temple of Solomon - Which is as ungodly today as it was in Solomon's time! Lastly, Solomon is a part of almost all occult religions and a book called the Key of Solomon is one of the main teaching tools to learn how to engage spirits. I'm not even going to get into Kabballah or Zionism. You are on to something but be aware of the rabbit hole you've just entered because it flips our world as we know it on it's head.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  However, it seems you've mistaken the purpose of this site.  I also need to point out that "who is right and who is wrong" is off-topic here.  I hope you choose to participate further, but before you do, you should read [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and then [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and
[What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)